# Can't see mesh I just created?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

when I open a new file in Blender 2.78 all things are normale I can create a Plane then I import a DXF file in the scene I begin modelling whith this plane ..Extrude ..ext then when I want to create a new plane or circle etc... they don't appear
I got a sphere a box but when I went to create a circle or a plane they don't show up but are listed in the Outliner with these properties with unchangeable Dimensions values
[image]

Comment: Try to set location to 0,0,0. They could be out of your sight.

Comment: Is you scene vertex count increasing by adding those "ghost" geom? Could you show the parameters in the command options panel? Is the one that pop up when you press F6 right after you run the add command.

Comment: The dimensions of the object is 0, looks like all the vertices are at the same place or were deleted.

Comment: Hi . thanks for all of you. 
if I create a Plan  all the vertices are in the same location at 0,0,0

Comment: not for the other forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the reason why when I create any object it will have the dimension of zero. that because the Grid lines scale is set to zero in display property.

Comment: The Scale option in the Properties shelf > Display rollout is responsible only for the scale between grid lines. It doesn't affect neither displayed nor actual mesh scale. The latter will change only if you change scale factor in scene settings.